# jQuery Ajax not returning variables from external PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, html, message-passing

I have this code that takes info from a form and sends it to form.php where it is processed. form.php echoes the variables (Fullname: $fullname E-mail: $email Link: $link Instructions: $instr) which are supposed to be inputted to #success. My code behaves two different ways in firefox and chrome.

In Firefox, I am sent to form.php which displays the output properly but obviously I shouldn't be sent there, I should stay on my main page and see that output in #success. Basically, the ajax doesn't work.

In Chrome, the ajax does work but only pulls Fullname: Email: Link: Instructions: into #success. In essence, the jQuery is not passing the variables via POST.

mainpage.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $(form).serialize();
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {   
            $.ajax({
            url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#success').html(result);
            }
            }); 
     event.preventDefault();
     });
})
</script>

<div id="exchange_inside">
<div id="formdiv">
<br>
<form method="post" id="form">
    Name / Nom:<input type="text" name="fullname" /><br />
    E-mail / Courriel:<input type="text" name="email" /><br />                          Your Daily URL / Votre URL Quotidien:<input type="text" name="link" /><br />
    Voting Instructions / Instructions de Vote:<textarea name="instr" style="width: 450px; height: 100px;"/></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="success">
</div>
```

form.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fullname'])){
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];   
}else{
    echo "No name";
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
}else{
    echo "No email";
}

if (isset($_POST['link'])){
    $link = $_POST['link'];   
}else{
    echo "No link";
}

if (isset($_POST['instr'])){
    $instr = $_POST['instr'];   
}else{
    echo "No instructions";
}

echo "Name: " .$fullname. " E-mail: " .$email. " Link: " .$link. " Instructions: " .$instr;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing up the jquery a bit by moving up `event.preventDefault();` to before the `ajax` call and fix your `var data = $("#form").serialize();`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();  
        var data = $("#form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#success').html(result);
        }
        }); 

 });
}); //semicolon here
```

Put a semicolon on the end of `$(document).ready` for good measure.

Moving `event.preventDefault()` before the `ajax` call stops the form from submitting if the `ajax` fails for some reason or there is an error in the `ajax` call. Primarily with this method of form submit, you want to stop the default behavior of the form first.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `$('#form').submit`, which is submitting the form without ajax, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('#form').serialize(); //this selector also needed to be fixed 
    $.ajax({
            url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#success').html(result);
            }
    }); 
});
```

**Edit:**
I misunderstood. Try serializing the data after submit has been pressed, rather than when the page loads, to fix the Chrome problem.

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {   
        var data = $('#form').serialize(); //moved this line and fixed selector
        $.ajax({
        url: '../wp-content/themes/MC/form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#success').html(result);
        }
        }); 
        event.preventDefault();
 });
```

You may also want to try changing the submit button to a regular button and binding the ajax to its onclick event. This would avoid problems with the form submitting without ajax, and fix the Firefox problem.

Comment: He wishes to make a XHR base form submission, not to send and empty form on dom ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form").submit(function(event) {   

         var data = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {

                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(xhr);
                $('#success').html(result.responseText);
            }

            });

    event.preventDefault();
        return false;
     });
})
```

1. Your declaration of data wasn't in the global scope.(i packed it in the right local scope)
2. $(form).serialize() isn't equal to $("#form").serialize()
3. Edit back in your url =)
4. Use Jsfiddle and Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools to test your code!

Hope that helps